# MySQL - update a certain column right after select

Tags: mysql

I ran into a problem and can't choose the right solution.

I have a **SELECT** query that selects records from table.
These records has an **status** column as seen below.

```
SELECT id, <...>, status FROM table WHERE something
```

Now, right after this **SELECT** I have to **UPDATE** the status column.
How can I do it to avoid a race condition?

What I want to achieve is once somebody (session) selected something, this something cannot be selected by anybody else until I do not release it manually (for example using a status column).

Thoughts?

Comment: Use a procedure to return results and add an update some flag column after the select.

Comment: Why do you SELECT it?

Comment: I select a customer and make an auto-call based on the phone_number field. The problem is if I already sent a customer to a call I do not want this customer to appear to another call-center guy. What happens now is that same customer appears for two or more call-center guys and this is not good.

Comment: SELECT ... FOR UPDATE is the method to achieve this .
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Answer (score 2):

[There](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) is some mysql documentation, thar may be interesting to solve your task, not sure if it fit you needs, but it describes right way to do select followed by update.

The technique described does not prevent other sessions reading, but prevent writing of selected record until the end of transaction.

It contains an example similar to your problem:

```
SELECT counter_field FROM child_codes FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE child_codes SET counter_field = counter_field + 1;
```

It is required that you tables use Innodb engine and your programs use transactions.

If you need locking only for short time, i.e. one session select row with lock, update it, and release lock in one session, then you do not need field status at all, just use `select ... for update` and `select ... lock in share mode` so if all sessions will use these two with conjunction with transactions `select... for update` then `update`  to modify, and `select ... with shared lock` to just read - this will solve your requirements.

If you need to lock for long time, select and lock in one session  and then update and release in another, then right you use some storage to keep lock statuses and all session should use as described below: `select ... for update` and set status and status owner in one session,  then in another session `select for update` check status and owner, update and remove status - for updating scenario,  and for read scenario: `select ... with shared lock` check status.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with some preparations. Add a column `sessionId` to your table. It has to be `NULL`-able and it will contain the unique ID of the session that acquires the row. Also add an index on this new column; we'll use the column to search for rows in the table.

```
ALTER TABLE `tbl`
  ADD COLUMN `sessionId` CHAR(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  ADD INDEX `sessionId`(`sessionId`)
```

When a session needs to acquire some rows (based on some criteria) run:

```
UPDATE `tbl`
SET `sessionId` = 'aaa'
WHERE `sessionId` IS NULL
  AND ...
LIMIT bbb
```

Replace `aaa` with the current session ID and `...` with the conditions you need to select the correct rows. Replace `bbb` with the number of rows you need to acquire. Add an `ORDER BY` clause if you need to process the rows in a certain order (if some of them have higher priority than others). You can also add `status = ...` in the `UPDATE` clause to change the status of the acquired rows (to `pending` f.e.) to let other instances of the code know those rows are processed right now.

The query above acquires some rows. Next, run:

```
SELECT *
FROM `tbl`
WHERE `sessionId` = 'aaa'
```

This query gets the acquired rows to be processed in the client code.

After each row is processed, you either `DELETE` the row or `UPDATE` it and set `sessionId` to `NULL` (release the row) and `status` to reflect its new status.

Also you should release the rows (using the same procedure as above) when the session is closed.

Comment: Is not there any beauty and convenient method? All I need is to read-lock the row/s that was/were selected in the last select statement and to have the ability to release it when I need.